# Passing values to Views

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to pass some values to another `View` from the `Controller`. My code so far;

```
success: function (response) {                            
    var text = response.responseText;
    if (result.status == "OK") {
        Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').push({
            title: 'Hello World ',
            html: ['<div>', '<b>HELLO PEOPLE</b>: ', '</div>'].join('')
        });
    }
}
```

The above code displays the `html` in another view.

In my project structure, i have a View called `AnotherView.JS`, i need to call this `View`, and pass the values to that `view` (`AnotherView.JS`). How can i modify the code to make these changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have two views FirstView and SecondView (xtype:'secondview') and you're in your FirstViewController, you need to add a reference to your second view like so :

```
config: {
  refs: {
    first: 'firstview',
    second:'secondview'
  }
}
```

Then, you can get the second view with `this.getSecond()` and do whatever you want with it

Hope this helps